# Use of `const` when declaring a parameter of a pointer type in C

Tags: c, pointers

I know that putting `const` before `p`'s type protects the object that `p` points to, but what about:

`void f(int * const p)`

Is such a declaration legal?

Also, what is the difference between the following:

1. `void f(const int *p)`
2. `void f(int * const p)`
3. `void f(const int * const p)`
4. `void f(int const *p)`

Comment: You forget one case: `void f(int const *p)`, which is the same as `void f(const int *p)`.

Comment: Thanks, I will edit the question to include this case.

Comment: @Rrz0; Why do you think this question should be asked again? Did you not find similar questions and answers on SO? Do you think answers on other questions didn't explain the topic well? If you have better explanations then don't you think you can post it as an answer on other similar posts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is such a declaration legal?

Yes, although the effect isn't the same as if `const` precedes `p`'s type.

> Also, what is the difference between the following:

1. `void f(const int *p)`

   Putting `const` *before* `p`'s type protects the object that `p` points to.

   Example:

   ```
   void f(const int *p) {
      int j;

      *p = 0;       //WRONG
      p = &j;       //legal
   }
   ```
2. `void f(int * const p)`

   Putting `const` *after* `p`'s type protects`p` itself.

   Example:

   ```
   void f(int * const p) {
      int j;

      *p = 0;       //legal
      p = &j;       //WRONG
   }
   ```

   This feature isn't used very after since `p` is merely a copy of another 
   pointer, there's rarely any reason to protect it. An even greater rarity is the 
   next case.
3. `void f(const int * const p)`

   Here `const` is protecting both `p` and the object it points to.

   Example:

   ```
   void f(const int * const p) {
      int j;

      *p = 0;       //WRONG
      p = &j;       //WRONG
   }
   ```
4. `void f(int const *p)`

   This is the same as `void f(const int *p)`. 
   See point 1.